# Reading xml -file in UTF-8 format in Windows with Java gives "IOException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence." -error

Tags: java, xml, parsing, utf-8

I have problem with my Java program. How I read xml -file which has "UTF-8" encoding. Program works correctly in Kubuntu but I doesn't work in Windows. Both OSes is writing xml -file correctly but parsing gives exception error in Windows.

```
String XMLFile = "ÄÄKKÖSET.xml"
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File (XMLFile));
```

Here is xml -file I need to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<deck created="04/04/2011">
  <title>ääkköset</title>
  <code>ÄÄKKÖSET</code>
  <description>ääkköset</description>
  <author>ääkköset</author>
  <cards nextCardID="1">
    <card color="#1364F9" id="0">
      <question>ÄÄKKÖSET</question>
      <answer>ÄÄKKÖSET</answer>
    </card>
  </cards>
</deck>
```

How do I get to read xml -file with Java in Windows without getting I get "IOException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence." -error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exception do you get? And is the file indeed written in UTF-8? Or, by any chance, just in Latin-1?

Comment: The code you posted parses *correct* UTF-8 encoded XML files correctly.

Comment: There is no subclass of `Throwable` named `ExceptionError`in Java ;) Please tell us the real error message

Comment: I get IOException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: This looks like your file is not really encoded in UTF-8. How did you check that it really is UTf-8? Or, how did you create it?

Comment: Can you try to save this file with these characters: `⚶⚲*Ѳǫɫ⅏℔Ӆ₧ȴɟLʈ!刄Ⱛ℀ȜS`? The characters that you currently have are defined both in UTF-8 and Latin-1, so the file might be saved as Latin-1, even though it should be UTF-8. Not all of the characters above are in Latin-1, so if your file is not Unicode, you'll see a line of `?????`s instead.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Program converted created xml -file with `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(sw.toString()));`
But I have forgot to add "UTF-8" -attribute. Like this:
`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(sw.toString()), "UTF-8");`
Now program is working correctly also in Windows environment.
Thanks for good advises to track down the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Your XML document has not been saved as UTF-8, the parser detects this (because not all byte sequences are legal UTF-8) and throws an error.

The solution is to save the file as UTF-8. It is not enough to declare the document as UTF-8 - the bytes the data is encoded to must match this declaration. By default, many text editors on Windows will default to saving data as ANSI.

Comment: Thank you for very good advice. I solved problem. I have forgot to add "UTF-8" -attribute. Like this:
`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml (sw.toString()), "UTF-8");`